# How to rewrite url path in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs

I want to rewrite url like '/api/example' to '/example'

I've tried code below, but it does not work

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class RewriteApiEndpointMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    req.originalUrl = req.originalUrl.replace(/^\/api/, '');
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution

Step 1:

```
consumer
  .apply(RewriteApiEndpointMiddleware)
  .forRoutes('/') // <--- not the .forRoutes('*')
```

Step 2:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class RewriteApiEndpointMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/api/, ''); // <--- not the .originalUrl
    next();
  }
}
```

Now it works as expected

Comment: Not sure how you got this to work, req.url is read only.