# Is there an easy way to keep query params on redirects in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am pretty new to this kind of stuff so any advice is appreciated, especially if there's a better way to solve this than what I am looking for.

I am trying to support an old endpoint by redirecting it to a new endpoint, and both endpoints should support query parameters. Each endpoint lives in a separate controller.

Example:
I want `/old-namespace/getStuff?foo=bar` to redirect to `/new-namespace/getStuff?foo=bar` without manually rebuilding a query string like the Nest docs point out, because the params can be dynamic.

Looking at the [NestJS docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#redirection), there is a handy `@Redirect` decorator that you can use on an endpoint like so, to easily redirect the request to a different URL:

```
@Get('docs')
@Redirect('https://docs.nestjs.com', 302)
getDocs(@Query('version') version) {
  if (version && version === '5') {
    return { url: 'https://docs.nestjs.com/v5/' };
  }
}
```

However, when using this, `request.query` is cleared on redirect (pretty sure this is expected behavior). Does anyone have a minimally-invasive solution for this? I've tested out building middleware/interceptors/custom decorators to get around this with varying degrees of success, but that seems heavy-handed and I wish there was a way to throw an extra param in the `@Redirect` decorator like `retainQuery = true` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the top answer here: [How to rewrite url path in Nestjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822989/how-to-rewrite-url-path-in-nestjs)

Ambroise Rabier's first response on nginx rewrites cued me in to search for a simple middleware solution since I didn't want to inject a service in multiple places, as there will be quite a few small redirects from old namespaces to new ones.

In a common module:

```
consumer
  .apply(RewriteApiEndpointMiddleware)
  .forRoutes('/')
```

In a middleware:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class RewriteApiEndpointMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
    // the linked answer replaced "api" but in my case I needed to send "app" requests somewhere else
    req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/app/, '/new-namespace');
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called rewrite in nginx.

I don't know if it work, but maybe you can do that ?

```
@Get('/old-namespace/getStuff')
getStuff(@Query() query) {
  // Done !
  getNewStuff(query);
}

@Get('/new-namespace/getStuff')
getNewStuff(@Query() query) {

}
```

If not, you can always do something like:

```
function handleGetNewStuff() {
}

@Get('/old-namespace/getStuff')
getStuff(@Query() query) {
  handleGetNewStuff(query);
}

@Get('/new-namespace/getStuff')
getNewStuff(@Query() query) {
  handleGetNewStuff(query);
}
```

---

However, if your issue is about changing the link on the user side (and not just for internal routing), you can try (not tested either):

```
@Get('/old-namespace/getStuff')
getStuff(@Req() request, @Res() response) {
  const newURL = req.originalUrl.replace('old', 'new');
  response.redirect(newURL);
}
```

Remember that NestJS use expressJS bellow.

Comment: Yeah I thought about going the injected service route but I was hoping for something less repetitive. Thank you for the suggestion on rewrites and reminder about Express--I'm going to try some rewrite middleware and see how it goes!