# Conditionally instantiate service class as a provider in NestJS

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a controller called `User` and two service classes: `UserAdminService` and `UserSuperAdminService`.
When a user makes a request to any endpoint of the `User` controller, I want to check if the user making the request is an Admin or a Super Admin (based on the roles in  the token) and instantiate the correct service (`UserAdminService` or `UserSuperAdminService`). Note that the two services implement the same `UserService` interface (just the internals of the methods that change a bit). How can I make this with NestJS?

What I tried:

*user.module.ts*

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: "UserService",
      inject: [REQUEST],
      useFactory: (request: Request) => UserServiceFactory(request)
    }
  ],
```

*user-service.factory.ts*

```
export function UserServiceFactory(request: Request) {

    const { realm_access } = JwtService.parseJwt(
        request.headers["authorization"].split(' ')[1]
    );
    if (realm_access["roles"].includes(RolesEnum.SuperAdmin))
        return UserSuperAdminService;
    else
        return UserAdminService;
}
```

*user.controller.ts*

```
  constructor(
      @Inject("UserService") private readonly userService: UserServiceInterface
  ) {}
```

One of the reasons my code is not working is because I am returning the classes and not the instantiated objects from the factory, but I want NestJS to resolve the services dependencies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than passing back the class to instantiate, which Nest doesn't handle, you could add the `UserSuperAdminService` and `UserAdminService` to the `inject` array, and pass back the instance that Nest then would create per request.

```js
providers: [
    {
      provide: "UserService",
      inject: [REQUEST, UserSuperAdminService, UserAdminService],
      useFactory: (request: Request, superAdminService: UserSuperAdminService, adminService: UserAdminService) => UserServiceFactory(request, superAdminService, adminService)
    }
...
]

export function UserServiceFactory(request: Request, superAdminService: UserSuperAdminService, adminService: UserAdminService) {

    const { realm_access } = JwtService.parseJwt(
        request.headers["authorization"].split(' ')[1]
    );
    if (realm_access["roles"].includes(RolesEnum.SuperAdmin))
        return superAdminService;
    else
        return adminService;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to conditionally instantiate a service class you could create a global middleware to redirect the request to the appropriate controller e.g.

```js
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AdminUserMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {
  
    const { realm_access } = JwtService.parseJwt(
        req.headers["authorization"].split(' ')[1]
    );
    
    if (realm_access["roles"].includes(RolesEnum.SuperAdmin)) {
        req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/, '/super-admin/');
       }

    next();
  }
}
```

Then you can apply it to all routes in your app.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  controllers: [UserAdminController, UserSuperAdminController]
  providers: [UserSuperAdminService, UserAdminService]
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AdminUserMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('/');
  }
}
```

and have the following controlers:

```js
@Controller('/')
export class UserAdminController {
  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(UserAdminController.name);

  constructor(private readonly userAdminService: UserAdminService) {}
```

```js
@Controller('/super-admin')
export class UserSuperAdminController {
  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(UserSuperAdminController.name);

  constructor(private readonly userSuperAdminService: UserSuperAdminService) {}
  
}
```

See the NestJS [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822989/how-to-rewrite-url-path-in-nestjs) for further details